# Remove duplicates indices in multiindex regardless of order

Tags: pandas, indexing, duplicates, series, multi-index

Take a simple `pd.Series` with a multi-index:

```
#create the multiindex and data
mult = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],names=['factor1','factor2'])
data = np.arange(1,4)*np.arange(1,4)[:,np.newaxis]

#create the series
ser = (pd.Series(data.ravel(),
                index=mult,
                name='product')
       .sort_values(ascending=False))

print(ser)
factor1  factor2
3        3          9
         2          6
2        3          6
         2          4
3        1          3
1        3          3
2        1          2
1        2          2
         1          1
Name: product, dtype: int64
```

How can duplicate indexes, *regardless of order*, be removed so the final series is

```
factor1  factor2
3        3          9
         2          6
2        2          4
3        1          3
2        1          2
1        1          1
Name: product, dtype: int64
```

The idea is `2*3` and `3*2` are the same factors and so we want to get rid of one.  I've tried `drop_duplicates`, but this eliminates any duplicate products regardless of their indices (so `1*0` and `2*0` would be considered duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hacky**

```
ser[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.array(ser.index.tolist()), 1)).duplicated().values]

factor1  factor2
3        3          9
         2          6
2        2          4
3        1          3
2        1          2
1        1          1
Name: product, dtype: int64
```